# C# Equivalent code in delphi for memory mapped files

Tags: c#, delphi, delphi-7, memory-mapped-files

I got code from one of the vendor to read something from Memory mapped file in C#, but due to limitations I need to develop the code in Delphi-7 language. The code I got is written below.

The tool is reading analog input from Hardware module.

Can any one help me to find equivalent code of C# in Delphi? My C# code is as below-

```
MemoryMappedFile file = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("MY_SHARED_LOCATION");
MemoryMappedViewAccessor reader = file.CreateViewAccessor();
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
         inputByte[i + 1] = reader.ReadByte(i);
}
```

I found equivalent Class of MemoryMappedFile but still unable to code rest of the part in Delphi-7.

Comment: I have no idea what the C# Code is really doing, but it looks like it might be as simple as reading a TFilestream 1 byte at a time. This link relates to .CreateViewAccessor() https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267546(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What makes you so sure this is asking for a recommendation?

Comment: @CraigYoung "Can any one help me to find equivalent code of C# in Delphi?" Frankly there's little to be gained for future readers from posts like this. I think they degrade the quality of the site. If you insist on answering them at least do the decent thing and downvote them so that they never rank high in a search.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You don't consider it possible that OP merely made a poor word choice as non first language English speaker?

Comment: @CraigYoung No, I think he just wants us to do his work for him. Witness the follow-up question from his other account, abandoning this one. This asker is a classic help vampire I am afraid. This site is somewhat overrun with them these days.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's a better than a lot of the rubbish questions I've seen. It has a simple code sample, and could be of use to someone who has seen `MemoryMappedFile` in C# but doesn't know how to do the equivalent in Delphi.

Comment: @CraigYoung I disagree. "Please translate my code from language A to language B" questions should always be removed in my view. That's my opinion at least.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm not aware of his other account and am considering this question on its own merit. I'm inclined to agree with you on the "translate A to B" questions. But in this case the sample code doesn't seem to serve much of a functional purpose. So it seems more like OP needs a pointer in the right direction - even though it's structured like a translation question. (Thanks for the heads-up in case OP goes off at  a tangent.)

Comment: @CraigYoung He's already abandoned this question to fester. He's moved on to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38078889/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Memory Mapped Files are feature provided by Windows for different processes to share memory.

I don't currently have access to a Delphi compiler to test this, but it should set you on the right path. I'm also making some assumptions based on the code sample you provided: You only intend reading data, you'll read exactly 16 bytes. If these are invalid, you'll have to changed the code accordingly.

```
hFile := OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_READ, FALSE, "MY_SHARED_LOCATION");
Win32Check(hFile);
try
  //Buffer must be a byte pointer
  buf := MapViewOfFile(hFile, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 16);
  Win32Check(buf);
  try
    //Use buf^ as you please
  finally
    UnmapViewOfFile(buf);
  end;
finally
  CloseHandle(hFile);
end;
```

For more info on the various memory map API routines, see the following:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms810613.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366556(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for helping with above code. It's working fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

"MemoryMappedFile" is a class which does use [memory mapped files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) feature of the Operating System to access a file content.

Under C#, there is no pointer, so it has a stream-oriented layout. But under Delphi, you have pointers, so you could easily use directly pointers over it.

There is a `TSynMemoryStreamMapped` class in our [SynCommons.pas](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SynCommons.pas) unit, which works well for Delphi 7 (and up), and do exactly what "MemoryMappedFile" does. You may consider `TFileBufferReader` or directly `TMemoryMap` and a PByteArray.

But using a memory mapped file is not worth it if you read a file from the beginning to the end. In this case, reading a file by chunks could be achieved by using a buffered stream. If your file is not huge, just use a `TMemoryStream` kind of stream.

Comment: And what if the asker doesn't want to take this third party dependency?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan There is no direct equivalency to the "MemoryMappedFile" class in the Delphi 7 RTL, for sure. I doubt using directly the API calls, and dealing with pointers, is within the asker's skills.
So, I proposed a ready-to-be-used class which provides the same feature set. As part of a third party library, for sure, since there is no such class in Delphi 7.
Then, the closest equivalency of the question is to use TMemoryStream.LoadFromFile, if the file size is not too huge - as I wrote in my answer.